# YII model - hide certain records

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a DB table with a field named "rstatus" which can have values "A" or "X"
How can I set a rule in the model for this table to take into account only the records with rstatus="A" ?

thanks

Comment: How are you currently getting the data?

Comment: a simple model made with Gii.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a [default scope](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes) to your model class:

```
public function defaultScope()
{
    return array
    ( 
        'condition' => " rstatus = 'A' " 
    );
}
```

Comment: If it would work out for you, press on the `V` sign to accept it as a correct answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complete wiki on [defaultScope](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/486/defaultscope/) and how to sometimes bypass it.